# result of a callback function in matlab gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have created a GUI in matlab with few buttons. Each button when clicked performs a certain function. Now I want to display the calculations being performed in the function to be displayed in a static textbox in the GUI. Is that possible? I am able to display it in the command window by removing the semicolon (;) at the end of the statement but I want it to be displayed in the GUI like a log.

Now when I click the "match" button the following function is called and I want to display whether it matches or not in the GUI in a textbox. Is that possible?

```
function matchin
[image1, pathname]= uigetfile('*.bmp','Open An image');
Directory = fullfile ('F:','matlab','bin');
D = dir(fullfile(Directory,'*.bmp'));
%imcell = {D.name}';
for i = 1:numel(D)
   if strcmp(image1,D(i).name)
       disp('matched');
   else
       disp('not matched');
   end
end;
```

I replaced the code with the one specified in the answer. Without using the text box the output in the matlab command window when I select the second file is

```
not matched
matched
not matched
not matched 
not matched
```

But if I use a static textbox only the last line is being displayed. How can I display all the 5 lines totally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

A good practice would be to save a structure with all the handles of your GUI elements by using the function guidata. For more information on this see [this link](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html).

Then in your callback you can retrieve this structure, for instance by:

```
handles = guidata(gcbo);
```

Then you can set the value of the textbox you want by replacing

```
if strcmp(image1,D(i).name)
   disp('matched');
else
   disp('not matched');
end
```

with:

```
if strcmp(image1,D(i).name)
   set(handles.handle_of_textbox,'String','matched');
else
   set(handles.handle_of_textbox,'String','not matched');
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this definitely and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: Reference to non-existent field 'htext'.

Error in matchin (line 11)
   set(handles.htext,'String','not matched');
 
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
I got the above error when i tried your solution. Where have i gone wrong??

Comment: htext=uicontrol(FigWin,...
    'Style','text','Position',[100 0 1270 100]);

Comment: I am very confused. Here, htext is my object handle for the text box?Am i right?

Comment: I suspect you do not save the handle properly. change: htext=uicontrol(FigWin,... 'Style','text','Position',[100 0 1270 100]);

into: 
handles.htext=uicontrol(FigWin,... 'Style','text','Position',[100 0 1270 100]);
guidata(handles.htext,handles);

Comment: myhandles = guidata(myhandles.htext);Now, i have specified this code in my callback function but, i am getting the following error:Undefined function or variable "myhandles".

Error in matchin (line 2)
myhandles = guidata(myhandles.htext);
 
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Comment: Just copy and paste my code, it should work, or read the documentation. since it seems like you are not really understanding what you are doing now.

Comment: Well yes i don't think what i am doing is correct. I am not getting any error but I can't see the text in the text box. Its empty.

Comment: If you put your two files at pastebin.com I will take a look at it.

Comment: This will be my final comment: the code to write in the textbox is working. However, the problem is with your other code. The for-loop is never accessed. Try to write in the textbox by placing the statement outside of the for-loop in matchin.m, this works perfectly. So good luck sorting out your code, my effort stops here, since your original question is answered.

Comment: how can I display more than on line in static text box??

Comment: the for loop works perfectly. I cant find what the problem is but, only last line is displayed.

Comment: Can you please help. Its really urgent.